# Repositioning JetPack's comment subscription box within WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, jetpack

I'm using WooCommerce and also utilising JetPck for a couple of things, one being it's comment subscription functionality.

Now, last time I checked it was displaying this fine, but I just now noticed that the "comment subscription box" you see when going to leave a review on a product is messed up - not sure if they moved it's position in a recent update or not.

Basically we now have the elements as such:

[image]

What I want is to have the `comment-subscription-box` *before* the `form-submit` element. Can this be done?

Comment: Can yo send the link of the website?